# How to disable libimobiledevice either completely or for a single specific external device?

Tags: virtualbox, 22.04, idevices

I am exploring passing an iPhone connection through to a VirtualBox guest. However, [something I read on the internet](https://superuser.com/questions/947582/kvm-iphone-passthrough-to-windows-guest) suggests that this kind of pass-through may be impeded by `libimobiledevice`'s "greedy" desire to grab any external device connection.

Is there a way I can temporarily disable `libimobiledevice` so I can explore passing the iPhone's connection through to the guest OS? Simply clicking "Unmount" on a `libimobiledevice`-mounted iPhone does not seem to make the device available to the guest OS.